# Django post data causing an error due to the value being in a list

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to get data from a form `POST`, but the one of the values in the data is causing an error:

```
ipdb> request.POST
<QueryDict: {'assign_to-autocomplete': [''], 'tasks': ['18'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['lVqkbkYdz42uTtLJviRIj3OukcwqsdvI'], 'assign_to': ['14'], 'action_type': ['assign_to']}>
```

the form data:

```
ipdb> self.form.data
{'assign_to-autocomplete': [''], 'tasks': ['18'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['lVqkbkYdz42uTtLJviRIj3OukcwqsdvI'], 'assign_to': ['14'], 'action_type': ['assign_to']}
```

I'm using `autocomplete_light` for the `assign_to` field, which is a `User`.

`assign_to` is a list of pks, and this seems to be causing a problem.

views.py:

```
class TasksPreviewView(MyMixin, FormView):
    ''' An intermediate page '''
    template_name = 'tasks/task_preview.html'

    def post(self, request):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        self.action_type = request.POST['action_type']
        form_class = self.get_form()
        self.form = form_class(data=dict(request.POST))

        if self.form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(self.form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(self.form)
```

forms.py:

```
class TaskBulkAssignToForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tasks = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Task.objects.all(), label='')
    assign_to = al.ModelChoiceField('UserStaffAutocomplete', queryset=User.objects.all(), required=True, label='Select a user')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' Filter down to the tasks of interest and set tasks as a hidden field '''
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        task_pks = (self.initial or self.data)['tasks']
        self.fields['tasks'].queryset = self.fields['tasks'].queryset.filter(
            pk__in=task_pks,
        )
        self.fields['tasks'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'hidden'

    def post_valid(self):
        ''' Called by form_valid '''
        # Do some processing
        # Return a success message

    def post_invalid(self):
        ''' Called by form_invalid '''
        # Return an error message

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('tasks', 'assign_to')
```

As a result of this, my form is always invalid, because it doesn't expect a list:
`django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']` Instead of a `user_pk` like `'14'`, `['14']` is passed in the `request.POST`. If I manually adjust the value to be `'14'` instead of `['14']` and `continue`, the form works beautifully as intended.

For some context, the `TasksPreviewView` is kind of an intermediate page, similar to the [Django admin page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/actions/). Each bulk action has its own form (in this case, the `assign_to` action). The first page redirects to an intermediate page with a form, but keeps all the objects in the GET. The second page (confirmation page) performs the `POST`. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of converting `request.POST` to a `dict`, you should be able to pass it in directly:

For example:

```
self.form = form_class(data=request.POST)
```

This is because request.POST is an instance of MultiValueDict that allows multiple values for each key.